# Enabling overflow: scroll into table cell with 100% width

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to do the following: http://www.pastebin.org/113337

I'm wondering why the scrolling won't take place? It just stretches the table. Try running the code with and without white-space: nowrap and see how it differs. Whenever I apply nowrap my table gets stretched. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Off-topic: what is `white-space: noflow` supposed to be? Don't you mean `nowrap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's just how tables work; they stretch when there's too much content in one of their cells.
Try putting a `<div>` inside your `<td>` and apply the width and overflow properties to that instead.

Addendum:

Your `table` has a CSS width property of `150px` while the `div` has a percentage, `%100`. Try giving the `<div>` a non-percentage width...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="150px;">
                <!-- wtv -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or try putting the whole `<table>` in a `<div>` with a fixed width...

```
<div style="width:150px">
    <table>
    <!-- wtv -->
    </table>
</div>
```

... lastly, I'd advise that you put your CSS in an external `.css` file ;)

Comment: I tried that. See my edited question, I put a div inside the td, but results are the same.

Comment: It does work fine when I set the width for the div manually, but I'd like to avoid that. That's why all the hassle. I use jQuery to change the table position and size, and I would like to only change one value, not a bunch of values. If that's not possible, then I guess I just have to manually calculate and update the size of the inner div, too, which makes skinning for this system much harder I'm afraid.

Comment: I think I'm going with that inner div approach and then just altering its size as well as the size of the table.

Comment: How about if you use the `class` attribute and external CSS rules?